# Gatling - Scala - Random String for every concurrent user

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm having trouble to find a way to generate a random string for every users that are in my simulations.

Right now, this obvious code does not works :

```
val email = "myEmail+"+random.nextInt(150000)+"@gmail.com"
var password = conf.getString("password")

var scn = scenario("All Auth Features")
scn = Scenarii.initUserAccount(scn)
scn = Scenarii.register(scn, email, password)
scn = Scenarii.loginUser(scn, email, password)
```

I have always the same email (obviously).

I also took a look at `feeder`, but that can't solve my issue because of a determined strings that are in a csv, for instance. I really need a random one.

I can't make something like this:

```
scn = Scenarii.register(scn, "myEmail+"+random.nextInt(150000)+"@gmail.com", password)
```

Executed each time because I need to use the exact same email in the following functions.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For posterity :

Found my solution using Feeder and Map :

```
val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map(("email","email+" + random.nextInt(150000) + "@gmail.com")))
var password = conf.getString("password")
var scn = scenario("All Auth Features")
scn = Scenarii.initUserAccount(scn)
scn = scn.feed(feeder)
scn = Scenarii.register(scn, "${email}", password)
scn = Scenarii.deleteAtRegister(scn)
scn = Scenarii.register(scn, "${email}", password)
```